# MYSQL Order By column_name with many table left joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a 4 table merge going on and in the end I want it to be sorted by an "ORDER BY" according to some variable. Right now this is always returning the same order of entries.

Something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['filter'])){
    $filter = $_GET['filter'];
#Example $filter = 'date' or team or game_num

    $q = $db->prepare("SELECT g.game_num, s.date,  t.team
                              FROM schedule n
                              LEFT JOIN g_lkp g
                              ON n.game_num = g.game_num
                              LEFT JOIN dates s
                              ON n.date = s.date
                              LEFT JOIN teams t
                              ON n.home_team_nbr = t.team                                 
                              ORDER BY '$filter' ");
$q->execute();
$qR = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($q->rowCount() > 0) {   
    foreach ($qR as $row) {
        echo '
```

Comment: why you are passing $fileter in `order by` as a string? it should not be constant - it should be somethng like: `order by g.game_num, s.date`.

Comment: It will come in through the page request such as /php/page.php?filter=date

Comment: also it is bad idea to put GET parameter into your SQL statement - it is straight way to get an SQL-injection vulnerability

Comment: Well I am using AJAX .load to load the php page with a query in it such as page.php?filter=date . How can I acheive it with POST? If thats what you mean

Comment: let me explain it for request `/php/page.php?filter=date` - because of quotes around $filter variable you will get `order by 'date'` but not `order by date`, so it would not sort by date ... it will sort by string constant 'date'.


about sql-injection - what if filter variable in request would be equal to `1'; DROP TABLE schedule;`?.. - you will lose all you data. so you should not pass variables from user directly to your sql statements.

Comment: Thanks I udnerstand why my SORT was not working and now it is!

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz - unfortunately, no RDBMS I'm aware of allows you to prepare column names as a parameter, so that wouldn't help him anyways.  He needs an explicit whitelist the he checks against server-side.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse That's right, it's an obsolete comment and I shall remove it. Thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//First check value of $filter
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT g.game_num game_num, s.date date,  t.team team
                          FROM schedule n
                          LEFT JOIN g_lkp g
                          ON n.game_num = g.game_num
                          LEFT JOIN dates s
                          ON n.date = s.date
                          LEFT JOIN teams t
                          ON n.home_team_nbr = t.team                                 
                          ORDER BY $filter ");
```